# Почему метод Object clone(); не клонирует нормально поля-объекты?

Tags: java

Почему метод Object clone(); клонирует поле-объект класса String и Integer, но не клонирует поле-объект который был создано мной (объект color класа Color)? И как тогда сделать чтобы клонировал. Кто знает, объясните пожалуйста.

Класс MyClass:

```
public class MyClass implements Cloneable {
String string;
Integer integer;
Color color;

MyClass(String string, Integer integer, Color color) {
    this.string = string;
    this.integer = integer;
    this.color = color;
}

@Override
protected Object clone() {
    try {
        return super.clone();
    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
        throw new InternalError();
    }
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "\nstring: " + string + "\ninteger: " + integer + color.toString();
}}
```

Класс Color:

```
public class Color{
String nameColor;
Color(String nameColor){
    this.nameColor = nameColor;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "\nColor = { nameColor: " + nameColor + " }";
}}
```

Класс Main:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args){
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass("Text", 100,new Color("red"));
    MyClass myClass1 = (MyClass) myClass.clone();
    myClass.string = "Another text";
    myClass.integer = 1000;
    myClass.color.nameColor = "green";
    System.out.println(myClass.toString());
    System.out.println(myClass1.toString());
}}
```

Результат работы программы:

```
string: Another text
integer: 1000
Color = { nameColor: green }

string: Text
integer: 100
Color = { nameColor: green }
```

Цвет изменился в обоих объектах...

Comment: Скопируйте старый объект перед клонированием. Там значение не должно поменяться. Поэтомуиего можно брать оттуда.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что он не знает как клонировать ваш объект, реализуйте вашим классом Color интерфейс `Cloneable`.

В методе clone() вам надо прописать создание нового объекта Color и присвоение полям нового объекта значений

```
public class Color implements Cloneable{
     String nameColor;

     Color(String nameColor){
         this.nameColor = nameColor;
     }
     ...

     @Override
     protected Object clone(){
         return new Color(nameColor);
     }
}
```

MyClass

```
public class MyClass implements Cloneable {
    String string;
    Integer integer;
    Color color;

    ...

    @Override
    protected Object clone() {
       return new MyClass(string,integer,color.clone());
    }

 }
```

Comment: Что я не так сделал? Оно не работает.
Я в классе Color реализовал интерфейс Cloneable.
И вот так переопределил метод:
`protected Object clone() {`
`Color c = new Color(this.nameColor);`
`return c;`
`}`

Comment: Добавьте в класс MyClass, метод clone(), для поля Color

Comment: я добавил пример в ответ